# How to enable ccache on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu, ccache

There is very little documentation on enabling `ccache` on GNU/Linux. Here is a response from [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net):

> At the moment, I think the best way to enable ccache is to add
>   "/usr/lib/ccache" to the front of your path. If you want to enable it
>   for all users by default, change the PATH variable in
>   /etc/environment.

Can someone give me more information on enabling `ccache`?

Comment: Hard to enable something you're not using. And how you're want to use it is a key. For make or compatible, export CC=ccache should work, if your makefile isn't too tricky one.

Answer (score 7):

In summary, there are two alternatives:

1. Prefix your compilation command with `ccache`, e.g. `ccache gcc -c example.c`.
2. Let ccache masquerade as the compiler. This is done by creating a symbolic link to ccache named as the compiler, e.g. by `ln -s /path/to/ccache /usr/local/bin/gcc`.

Some Linux distributions often set up a `/usr/lib/ccache` directory with symbolic links similar to alternative 2 above, and then you can just add `/usr/lib/ccache` to `PATH` (e.g. with `PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:"$PATH"`) to enable ccache.

See also the [ccache manual](https://ccache.dev/manual/4.8.3.html), especially the [Run modes](https://ccache.dev/manual/4.8.3.html#_run_modes) section which describes how to enable ccache.

Comment: This _is_ the *preferred* way of using `ccache` to date (2023)

Comment: @RayOei, what is the preferred way? reading the manual, or prepending `/usr/lib/ccache`? The latter isn't mentioned in the manual.

Answer (score 7):

### Download latest version of [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) for better performance.

**After Downloading, Follow the steps as mentioned below:**

**A) Tar the file using the following command :**

```
$tar -xvf ccache-3.2.4.tar.bz2
 
Note : I'm using ccache 3.2.4 Version.You can download the latest one.
```

**B) Go inside ccache-3.2.4 folder and run the following commands:**

```
$./configure
$./make 
$ sudo make install
```

**C) Go to your .bashrc and insert the following :**

```
export CCACHE_DIR=/home/user_name/.ccache
export CCACHE_TEMPDIR=/home/user_name/.ccache

Note : Fill user_name with your User Name
```

**D) Save your Bashrc and source it**

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

**E) To check ccache is working or not type :**

```
ccache -M 10G : To Set the ccache Size to 10GB
```

**F) To check ccache is working or not type :**

```
ccache -s : To check ccache statistics
```

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two methods:

i) Override the `CC`, `CXX`, ... flags in a Makefile.  Within the R framework, a system and optional user configuration file is read, and I simply set

```
VER=4.7
CC=ccache gcc-$(VER)
CXX=ccache g++-$(VER)
SHLIB_CXXLD=g++-$(VER)
FC=ccache gfortran
F77=ccache gfortran
```

which also allows me to switch back and forth between `gcc` versions.  Now *all* compilations involving R use `ccache`.

ii) For other uses, I have deployed the fact that `/usr/local/bin/` is checked prior to `/usr/bin`.  So one can do

```
root@max:/usr/local/bin# ls -l gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 27 11:04 gcc -> /usr/bin/ccache
root@max:/usr/local/bin# ./gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@max:/usr/local/bin#
```

and now `gcc` is invoked via `ccache`:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ cp -vax ~/src/progs/C/benfordsLaw.c .
`/home/edd/src/progs/C/benfordsLaw.c' -> `./benfordsLaw.c'
edd@max:/tmp$ time /usr/local/bin/gcc -c benfordsLaw.c 

real    0m0.292s
user    0m0.052s
sys     0m0.012s
edd@max:/tmp$ time /usr/local/bin/gcc -c benfordsLaw.c 

real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility (instead of `export CC=ccache` commented by Keltar), if `$HOME/bin/` is listed in your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin/`, would be to make a symlink

```
 ln -s /usr/bin/ccache $HOME/bin/gcc
```

Then every [execvp(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) of `gcc` would find that symlink

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu install ccache

1. **sudo apt-get install ccache**
2. Confirm installation execution after installation **"which ccache"**

```bash
$ which ccache
/usr/bin/ccache
```

3. Add the following contents to the "~/.bashrc"  or  "~/.zshrc==" file

```bash
# ccache
export USE_CCACHE=1
export CCACHE_SLOPPINESS=file_macro,include_file_mtime,time_macros
export CCACHE_UMASK=002
```

**source "~/.bashrc"** or **"~/.zshrc"**
4. The 5 GB disk space set by default for ccache is normally enough. If you are worried about it, you can increase it, **ccache -M 30G**
5.  Confirm successful installation through version

```bash
$ ccache --version
ccache version 3.4.1

Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Andrew Tridgell
Copyright (C) 2009-2018 Joel Rosdahl
```

6. You can view the current configuration through **ccache - s**

```bash
cache directory                     /home/username/.ccache
primary config                      /home/username/.ccache/ccache.conf
secondary config      (readonly)    /etc/ccache.conf
stats zero time                     Fri Jul 22 16:15:40 2022
cache hit (direct)                  4186
cache hit (preprocessed)             875
cache miss                          1069
cache hit rate                      82.56 %
called for link                      653
cleanups performed                     0
files in cache                      3209
cache size                          159.3 MB
max cache size                      30.0 GB
```

### Use libzmq to test ccache

1. Through **github** download the source code of **libzmq**

```bash
$ git clone  https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git
Cloning into 'libzmq'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 43791, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
remote: Total 43791 (delta 11), reused 24 (delta 8), pack-reused 43755
Receiving objects: 100% (43791/43791), 21.91 MiB | 1.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (31951/31951), done.
```

2. Create the **build** directory in the **libzmq** directory
3. Modify **CMakeLists. txt** , '+' to add

```
──────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: CMakeLists.txt
───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ # CMake build script for ZeroMQ
   2   │ project(ZeroMQ)
   3   │ 
   4   │ if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL Darwin)
   5   │   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
   6   │ else()
   7   │   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
   8   │ endif()
   9   │ 
  10 + │ find_program(CCACHE_FOUND ccache)
  11 + │ if(CCACHE_FOUND)
  12 + │     set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE ccache)
  13 + │     set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_LINK ccache)
  14 + │     message(STATUS "use ccache")
  15 + │ endif(CCACHE_FOUND)
  16 + │ 
  17   │ include(CheckIncludeFiles)
```

4. Execute **"cmake .."** In the **build** directory
   Print and display **"-- use ccache" **means enable **ccache**, but note that when each project is enabled **ccache** for the first time, it will not speed up the compilation speed, but save the compilation cache to the **"/home/username/. cache"** directory for later compilation

```bash
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- use ccache
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
...
```

5. Use the **"/usr/bin/time"** command to record the compilation time

```bash
/usr/bin/time make -j3

result:
48.79user 14.25system 0:21.60elapsed 291%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 176036maxresident)k
0inputs+282248outputs (0major+2406923minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

6. **"rm - rf *"** delete **build** all files in the directory
7. **cmake ..**
8. Use the **"/usr/bin/time"** command to record the compilation time

```bash
/usr/bin/time make -j3

result:
2.78user 2.42system 0:02.15elapsed 241%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 23736maxresident)k
0inputs+21744outputs (0major+232849minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

https://www.cnblogs.com/jiangyibo/p/16516932.html